How to reset levels?
My filament stopped extruding but printer kept going up levels. How do I put the nozzle back to the level needed and finish printing?

Hi Mark, welcome to 3DPrinting.SE. this is considered a duplicate as this is similar to this question: "How to resume an unfinished project?", with this accepted answer.
